# Pushing an object into an array gone wild

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

So I've tried rewriting this but something's very strange. I'm running this from a `<script>` to chrome console.

```
        var time1 = { title: "asd", start: new Date().setHours(6), end: new Date().setHours(18) };
        var time3 = { title: "asadsdasd", start: new Date().setHours(9), end: new Date().setHours(14) };
        console.log(time1);
        console.log(time3);
        var times = new Array();
        times.push(time1);
        times.push(time3);
        console.log(times);
```

results in:

```
Object {title: "asd", start: 1439873498217, end: 1439916698217}

Object {title: "asadsdasd", start: 1439884298217, end: 1439902298217}

[Object, Object]
   0: Object end: undefined start: undefined title: "Event: undefined"
   1: Object end: undefined start: undefined title: "Event: undefined"
```

What bothers me most is this "Event: undefined". How does that even happen? I do not even run any script in between this. I am using fullcalendar, jquery and jquery-ui but I have searched in fullcalendar for `"Event: undefined"` in case they have some strange code that causes this but no results

Also, I have tried running this in nodejs and it works fine, so I'm actually looking for hints where to look for bugs

I'm getting this in this section of my cshtml file:

```
@section scripts{
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/calendar_view")

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var time1 = { title: "asd", start: new Date().setHours(6), end: new Date().setHours(18) };
        var time3 = { title: "asadsdasd", start: new Date().setHours(9), end: new Date().setHours(14) };
        var time2 = { title: "qwe", start: "2015-08-19T01:00:00", end: "2015-08-19T18:00:00" };
        console.log(time1);
        console.log(time3);
        var times = new Array();
        times.push(time1);
        times.push(time2);
        console.log(times);
        fullcalendar_init(times);
    });
  </script>
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pkc7rez3/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Yeah, I've tried running it in nodejs and it works ok as well so I've made an edit. I am aware that this should work

Comment: when are you getting this problem - is there any steps to recreate the issue

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries at the same time? I got weird behaviour from Array when using Ember.js for example.

Comment: I've edited with more context, but there are outer views and such, although nothing I'd consider important

Comment: I'm using jquery, jquery-ui and fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out (and as many have guessed), the issue was with the fullcalendar lib and me not reading the documentation because I was supposed to pass `{'events': [ event1, event2 ] }`  while I was only passing `{[event1, event2]}`

The only thing that bothers me is that somehow this change happened in between 2 lines of my code where I assigned a value and then printed it out and without any console log errors or anything so I was left wondering. I even searched the script for the wierd `Event: undefined` string in the script but it was generated in some way as to be untraceable